# RHEL 7.2 How to backup install

Tags: image, backup, redhat

I have installed RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.2 on two systems, one of the systems was issued to a developer and after a few days a problem occurred, which we couldn't resolve so we decided to rebuild the system which took quite a while.  However now that the system is back up and running and ready to go, I would like to take a backup of the state it is in now, so that if another fault occurs we can restore the image from the backup.

But how?  I've searched around and can find nothing for RHEL versions newer than v6.

I would like to create an image of the system to DVD and be able to restore from DVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can backup with **dump**  and restore it with **restore**

please check these 2 commands:

```
man restore
man restore
```

FYI:

- 33.6. Making backups with dump http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap29sec309.html
- 33.7. Restoring files with dump http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap29sec310.html